# How can I Verify amazon seller id

Tags: amazon-mws

I'm trying to create an app for Amazon sellers with the MWS API. How can I verify a seller ID that has been given to me for the MWS panel authorization?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For verification of seller account required following values:

```
MWS::Feeds::Client.new({ 
  primary_marketplace_id: marketplace_id,
  merchant_id: seller_id,
  aws_access_key_id: api_key,
  aws_secret_access_key: api_secret
})
```

***marketplace_id**: A marketplace is an Amazon market where the seller can list items for sale and customers can view and purchase items. Each Amazon marketplace has a unique ID associated with it. Multiple marketplaces can exist in a single country. Example: www.amazon.com and www.amazon.co.uk

marchant_id, aws_access_key_id, and aws_secret_access_key all are available in Amazon account.